# Why does SmtpMail not send unless from/host are set in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to send an email using SmtpMail. On my local server, I can do this even if the code has the host/server, password and from info set in the code. On my hosting service (1and1) it will only send if I set those things in the web.config file! Does anyone know what might cause this (1and1 has no idea).

**Works Locally but NOT on hosting servcie**

```
<%@ Page language="c#" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
<%

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    //Set my from address
    mail.From = new MailAddress( "myemail@myemail.com");

    //Who I'm sending to
    mail.To.Add( new MailAddress("you@you.com") );

    mail.Subject = "A test";
    mail.Body = "Test message";

    //Set the mail server (default should be smtp.1and1.com)
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient( "smtp.1and1.com" );

    //Enter your full e-mail address and password
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@myemail.com", "mypassword");

    //Send the message
    smtp.Send(mail);

%>
```

**THIS IS HOW I GET IT TO WORK ON HOSTING (two files, the test page and web.config)**

```
<%@ Page language="c#" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
<%

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    //Set my from address
    mail.From = new MailAddress( "myemail@myemail.com");

    //Who I'm sending to
    mail.To.Add( new MailAddress("you@you.com") );

    mail.Subject = "A test";
    mail.Body = "Test message";

    //Create with no server or credentials (grabs from web.config)
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    //Send the message
    smtp.Send(mail);

%>
```

(and web.config)

```
    <configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="myemail@myemail.com">
                <network host="smtp.1and1.com" port="25" userName="myemail@myemail.com" password="mypassword"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What happens when you don't set it in the web.config?  I assume you get an error, what is the error?

Comment: @CodingGorilla yes, I get different things depending on the browser. In Firefox it asked me to download the "test.aspx" file but said it was 0 bytes. In IE it says there was a timeout error.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense, if you're being prompted to download the file then the server is returning the wrong content type.  In either case, you never see any error messages?

Comment: @CodingGorilla In IE I see a timeout error (it's an SMTP error)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are not setting SMTP port when working with your local code but that you do set it in web.config. Have you tried manually adding SMTP port like this:

```
smtp.Port = 25;
```

Also, have you tried setting EnableSsL property manually?

Comment: I did not try setting the port (but isn't this the default port?). I did try the "EnableSsl" but that didn't help.

Comment: Yeah, 25 is the default port but who knows what may be the reason. I'd always try with the simple things first before going into anything more complex.